# Web2Py adding a file to a DB

Tags: python, file-io, web2py

I'm creating a file in my Web2Py code as follows:

```
tmpPckUpFile = open('FileContent.txt', 'w+')
```

I add to it

```
tmpPckUpFile.write("some stuff")
```

I close the file

```
tmpPckUpFile.close()
```

then try to update a row in the DB

```
db(db.project_pickup_approvals.id==request.args(0)).update(PickupContent = tmpPckUpFile)
```

At this point, I generally get an error:
 **I/O operation on closed file**

so what I've tried doing is removing the close() and now the file gets added to the DB but nothing is written. I get a blank file.

Q: How can I write to the file and place it into the DB?

Comment: Perhaps you need to use something like `tmpPckUpFile.seek(0)` instead of closing the file. (Having said that, I don't know what the `db.update()` method can do).

Comment: what does seek() do?

Comment: It moves the internal pointer. In this case moving it back to the beginning of the file so the contents can be read again. What does `db.update()` do?

Comment: it performs an update on a row in the table

Comment: And how does the update know to use file contents?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to retain the original "FileContent.txt" temporary file on the filesystem, you can instead write the content to a `StringIO` object, which is a file-like object that does not require the creation of an actual file on the filesystem.

```
import cStringIO
tmpPckUpFile = cStringIO.StringIO()
tmpPckUpFile.write('some stuff')
tmpPckUpFile.seek(0)
upload_field = db.project_pickup_approvals.PickupContent
db(db.project_pickup_approvals.id == request.args(0)).update(
    PickupContent=upload_field.store(tmpPckUpFile, filename='myfile.txt'))
tmpPckUpFile.close()
```

The above code should also work if you replace the first two lines with your original `tmpPckUpFile = open('FileContent.txt', 'w+')` line.